# Excel Macro run time error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a very simple macro that deletes a number of columns from a work book, but when I run it I get the error Run-Time error "1004": Application-Defined or object defined error.

```
Dim y As Long

y=46
Do While y>27

columns (4*y).Select
Selection.Delete
y=y-1

Loop
```

It is weird, since I copied and pasted this exact line of code from another macro and that one works just fine.

As a side note on the excel sheet I inserted a button, to set up my macro in case that matters

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work. I am not sure if you just had it exactly like you typed it and did not separate your lines out

```
Sub test()


Dim y As Long

y = 46
Do While y > 27

Columns(4 * y).Select
Selection.Delete
y = y - 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what the problem but I just rewrote the thing and it works.

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, please mark the response as the answer.